# Amdahl's Law for specific heavy tasks

Tags: multithreading, math, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, parallelism-amdahl

I have a set of tasks(sending SMS by GSM modem) which can be executed fully paralleled, but one sms task could not. Each task takes about lets say 10 second to execute. So now i am trying to evaluate how it would behave with 4 GSM modem.

**Amdahl’s law**

```
Speedup=1/((1-p)+P/s)
```

In my case p=1 as the tasks are fully paralleled, and s=4 (GSM modems)

Thus

```
Speedup = s
```

**Question**
How can i represent such cases in my counts

```
NumberOfTasks % s != 0
```

For example if i have 5 GSM modems but there is only one SMS to send,  my task is not paralleled at all, but with this law i am getting that the speedup is 5.

So it really takes 10 seconds, but by Amdahl’s  law i am getting 10/5=2 second

Comment: This is a mis-application of Amdahl's Law.  The task is the sending of one SMS and there is no parallelisation possible (according to the problem statement) for that task.  If it takes `s` seconds to send one SMS how long does it take to send `T` with `p` processes ?  It takes `T/p*s`, and that's the end of it.  If you really must apply Amdahl's Law remember that it answers the question of how performance scales for a fixed load - and fix your load at, say, `x,000` SMS sends.

Comment: Thanks Mark, after your answer i decided to not use Amdahl's law. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### How to correctly apply the Amdahl's argument:

Dr. Gene AMDAHL has formulated the law quite some time ago, when processing flows organization improvements were in focus for mainframe computing centres, for industrial production, for generic work-flow optimisations. This law is still valid and has its word to say.

[image: The PRINCIPAL ceilings for Speedup <code>S</code>]

The process-oriented point of view has remained a bit out of sight in the simplicity of the traditional formula, but should never been. The same applies to the "inventory" of ( somewhat specialized, "product"-specific ) resources. If interested in more details, one may re-read the **[parallelism-amdahl](/questions/tagged/parallelism-amdahl)** details from history #3 in https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3

Both the paragraphs, with re-formulated Amdahl's law, in the chapter **Criticism**, have all the details about the rationale why we cannot simply put numbers into a formula and expect a valid ( i.e. reasonable and achievable ) result.

### So, lets start with an abstraction of the PROCESS:

The one, identified and named above, is the process of sending an SMS message. It can take ~ 10 [s]. This process is independent ( hooray, no coordination, no barriers, no semaphores, no locks, no process-to-process communications ), but indivisible in length, so for brevity, we may call it an **atomic-process** as it cannot be performed but in a complete "atomically"-indivisible fashion, but it has some latency ( duration ), before a process-finished state could be reached.

Each of the processes will work only **if and only if** when it has been both mapped ( allocated ) and scheduled ( activated/executed ) onto some processing resource.

### So, next the RESOURCES:

As there has been already defined in the original post, there are 4-SMS-modems. These are process-specific resources, that are responsible for carrying the "atomic"-process ( task ) independently of one from the others ( which is a simple case here, not automatically extensible ad infinitum, as the carrier network will start blocking, once the radio-access-network ( GSM last-mile ), POP-processing ( BTS-node ) and/or carrier-network ( uplinks from BTS to MSC ) will start to reach their respective resouces' available capacities ceilings - all complex systems simply have complex hierarchies of resources / capacities / workloads allocations / performance-related ceilings where each may start blocking of some of our "atomic"-process-of-interest latency ( duration ) and "schedulability" ( a mapping of a process onto "our" identified unit of process-specific processing-resource ... i.e. the GSM-modem has some amount of the background logic, related with the GSM-network coordination, so its behaviour is not isolated from the complexity of the local GSM-cell traffic, processed on both the local BTS-node and also on the complex BTS/MSC-network processing/traffic transport coordination conditions, which we do not observe but indirectly, by increased latency or even by a denial of service response, if BTS-node is not able to handle our "atomic"-process request and discards it after some GSM-standard driven timeouts, as it is unable to receive and carry the SMS - thus the SMS is known to be a not-guaranteed messaging service by-design since ever ).

So, lets keep the simple assumption, that SMS-modem will always process the request to send an SMS, so in this resources-management simplified case the only limiting factor is the number of SMS-modems - here, being **4**

### Overhead-strict and resources-aware re-formulation:

```
                          1                       Where: s      := a SERIAL only part of the End-to-End process-flow
S =  ____________________________________________        1 - s  := a PARALLEL organizable part
                   / ( 1 - s )           \               pSO    := a PARALLEL task setup overhead
     s + pSO + max|  _________ , atomicP  | + pTO        pTO    := a PARALLEL test termination overhead
                   \     N               /               N      := a number of resources that process  atomic-process-block
                                                         atomicP:= a duration of a further indivisible atomic-process-block
```

### Result:

For a mock-up situation, where actual times are:

```
   Ts       =  X [s] a duration to launch the End-to-End process-flow ( start the program ),
   TatomicP = 10 [s] a latency of sending one SMS-message will never be shorter,
    Nres    =  5 [1] a number of SMS-messages processing resources ( i.e. GSM-modems ),
    nSMS    =  1 [1] a number of SMS-messages to send,
   TpSO     =  Y [s] a duration to start a PARALLEL sub-process for GSM-modem pool handling,
   TpTO     =  Z [s] a duration to disengage the pool of PARALLEL sub-processes and to release all of their owned resources,
```

thus the End-to-End process-flow duration **`T_E2E`** will be:

**`T_E2E = Ts+TpSO+max(TatomicP*nSMS/Nres, TatomicP)+TpTO) = X + Y + max(10/Nres, 10) + Z`**

the fraction **`s`** of the pure-`SERIAL` process flow, that will always have to remain pure-`SERIAL`, will be:

`( Ts ) / ( T_E2E ) = X / ( X + Y + 10 + Z ) [1]`

the principal ceiling ( a maximum ever achievable ) Speedup **`S`** will be:

`( Ts + TatomicP*Nsms ) / ( Ts + TpSO + max(TatomicP*nSMS/Nres,TatomicP) + TpTO )`, which for just one SMS-message and whatever large number of SMS-processing GSM-modems will be here << 1, right because the pure-`SERIAL` process-flow does exhaust no time to neither setup a pool of sub-processes and to finally terminate them and release the pool's allocated resources and spends no time to arrange transfers of data there and back, among the main-task and the pool of tasks organised in a true `PARALLEL` fashion.

So, here, you pay way more than you receive back ( from the process organisation point of view, the pool of processing-ready GSM-modems ( resources ) is rather expensive to arrange and control so as to send just one SMS-message ).

In case the End-to-End workflow starts to process a larger cohort of SMS-messages, the performance will boost and the speedup **`S`** will do the same. The larger the cohort to process the better. The larger the cohort to process and the more the GSM-modems to process the cohort, the better.

Yet, the Amdahl's argument sets the principal ceiling of such achievable speedups:

the **`S`** will principally never be more than 4 for 4 modems, not more than 5 for 5 modems etc.